# how to find matrix exponental of a fourth order matrix in Maple12

Tags: matrices, maple

how to find matrix exponental of the fourth order matrix in Maple 12 given below
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-2&3&1&0\\
1&-4&1&1\\
0&1&-3&2\\
4&0&3&-1\end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

0% accept rate, you should fix that!

You need to load the linear algebra package, (with(LinearAlgebra):) and then compute the first four terms in the exponential series